# Does Energy change sign when time is reversed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry

In classical physics if one reverses time then energy does not change sign. For example in the formula for kinetic energy one has:

$$E = \frac{1}{2}m v^2$$

If you reverse time the velocity $v$ changes to $-v$ but $E$ stays the same.

What happens in quantum mechanics?

In QM one has the formula:

$$E = h \nu = \frac{h}{\Delta t} $$

If $\Delta t$ changes to $-\Delta t$ then in QM the energy should change sign if the time is reversed.

Why is there a difference between classical and QM?

Comment: If there was no difference between classical and quantum mechanics there would be no need for such distinction :)

Answer (score 5):

Energy, frequency and period are all scalars. It's correct to write:

$$ E = \frac{h}{\tau} $$

where $\tau$ is the period, but the sign of $\tau$ does not change if you run time backwards so the sign of energy doesn't change in QM either.

Comment: That was also my guess, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: What about momentum? Classically it's $\mathbf{p}=m\mathbf{v}$ so it changes sign when time is reversed. But in QM we have $p = h/\Delta x$.

Comment: @JohnEastmond: momentum is $\mathbf{p}=\hbar\mathbf{k}$ where $k$ is the wave vector. Because $\mathbf{k}$ is a vector $\mathbf{p}$ is as well. If you write $p = h/\Delta x$ this only makes sense if you identify $\Delta x$ with $\hat{x}\lambda/2\pi$ ($\hat{x}$ is the unit vector in the $x$ direction) in which case the quantity you've called $\Delta x$ is also a vector.

Answer (score 5):

As John Rennie wrote in his answer, what one should consider is not a generic $\Delta t$ but the period $\tau$ which is a positive number. However positivity also arises form coherence with other relations. In particular, in relativistic quantum mechanics $E= \sqrt{\hbar^2 \vec{k}^2 + m^2c^4}$. For $m=0$ you have $E= \hbar |\vec{k}| = \hbar \omega = h\nu$ where $\omega$ and $\nu =1/\tau$ are therefore supposed to be non negative. These numbers are trivially invariant under time reversal.